# ffmpeg breaks with -threads argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to limit ffmpeg to one thread, however I can't get this command to run (from Python):

```
command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-loglevel", "error",
    "-y",
    "-pix_fmt", "gray",
    "-s", "%dx%d" % (data.shape[1], data.shape[0]),
    "-r", "30",
    "-c:v", "rawvideo",
    "-f", "rawvideo",
    "-i", "-", # Input from stdin
    "-crf", str(crf),
    "-c:v", "libx264",
    "-preset", preset,
    "-f", "matroska",
    "-threads", "1"
    "-" # Output to stdout
]
```

It worked fine without the -threads argument., but now it gives the error: "At least one output file must be specified". I suppose because it's right before the output file argument. I've tried various positions for the -threads argument, but all result in some kind of error.

Comment: Closing as a programming question and a simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a comma after the `1` in `"-threads", "1"`.

Comment: That's correct ... that's really stupid of me, sorry. I'm surprised it didn't even give a syntax error in Python.